# Vehicle squeaking 3-4 times when beginning to drive. Stops after getting some speed

Tags: brakes, automatic-transmission, noise

Recently I've noticed that my 2012 Nissan Frontier (Automatic Transmission) is squeaking when I start driving from a complete stop. It will only squeak 3-4 times and will go away once I've gained some speed (15 km/h). It's fairly loud so I assume that it's coming from the front of the vehicle. This happens at all stop signs, red lights etc.

I'm going to give my dealership a call, but would appreciate having some knowledge of what it might be before I do so.

Any advice on what the issue could be would be appreciated!

Comment: Any chance you can post a video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would venture to assume it is your brakes which are talking to you. I bet the "squealer" is close enough to engage the rotor at certain points. Once the vehicle speed is fast enough it will not make the noise, or is covered up by road noise. I doubt, from your description, it has anything to do with the transmission itself.

Comment: This was the issue. I had my rear brakes 'serviced' and it removed the issue there (still exists in the front). I think I should be able to fix this issue on my own by sanding down my brakes a bit. However, my next move will likely be new brakes & rotors anyway, so I might just wait for that.

Comment: Better late than never!

Answer (score 2):

This may be a longshot since it only occurs when accelerating, but it could be the rubber hood stops under the hood squeaking. You could try turning them out one or two rotations to see if that stops the squeak, or add some of those furniture foot pads underneath.  This sound is most noticeable over speed-bumps or potholes.

I had a squeak in my 2011 Frontier that was really pissing me off, turned out to be the hood stops. Research showed this is a common issue for these trucks. Based on the conditions in which your problem occurs, I dont think this is the root of your issue, but giving this a shot will only waste 1 minute of your time and rule out a common source of squeakiness for Frontiers.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for a squeak when you accelerate would be a busted motor mount, especially on transverse engines.

BUT, I would check the brakes and hood stops first, as suggested by the other answers.